# Disabling Certain iPhone Functions

Tags: ios, iphone

This is pretty straightforward from reading the title. I am looking for some sort of function that I can run inside of an application on an iPhone that will disable certain phone functions (e.g. Messages, Snapchat, etc.). If anybody knows how to do this, I cannot find this functionality. Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible for an App Store app.

Comment: Actually, this is not even possible unless the device is Jailbroken.

Comment: @Oskar how do applications such as CellControl do it? Do you have any idea? https://www.cellcontrol.com/stop-texting-while-driving-for-your-family

Comment: It doesn't. A quick look at their App Store listing reveals that their app can only track trips and give you a score for not using the phone, not control the features of the phone.

Comment: It's only possible with mobile device management (MDM) https://support.apple.com/business